# Graphic intersecting asymptotes

Tags: calculus, asymptotics

Sometimes graphics intersect the asymptotes(horizontal) of the function we plot and then they tend to the asymptote to infinity.What gives us the information whether the graph only tends to the asymptote and does not intersect it or intersects the asymptote a  then tends to her for a given point?

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+%28x-1%29^3%2F%28x%2B1%29^2 y=x-5 is the horizontal asymptote,x=1 is inflection point and why the graphic isnt under y=x-5?

Comment: That graph in the comment link is $y=x-1$, which has no horizontal asymptote and no inflection point. Why did you include this link?

Comment: the link continues but it is not detected,however I think I answered myself the question.When we have inflection point and we know it's concativity we just have to plug it in f(x) and find it's cordinates then we can easily do the rest

Comment: However it seems that sometimes it is hard to find the roots of the second derivative and check for concativity from which we get if there are any additional inflex points which helps us make the graph look more precise

Comment: I'm sorry, but your comments are very unclear, especially since your first comment makes no sense. Why don't you edit your main question to clarify your issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those two issues are quite separate: (1) whether a function's graph intersects a horizontal line, and (2) whether the horizontal line is an asymptote to the function's graph.

Let us say that the function is $y=f(x)$ and the horizontal line is $y=b$. You find if they intersect by solving the equation $f(x)=b$. You find if the line is an asymptote by checking if either $\lim_{x \to -\infty}f(x)=b$ or $\lim_{x \to +\infty}f(x)=b$.

Some examples: The function $f(x)=\frac 1x$ has the horizontal asymptote $y=0$ but does not intersect it. It does intersect $y=1$, which is not an asymptote.

The function $f(x)=\frac{\sin x}x$ also has $y=0$ as a horizontal asymptote, but here the function does intersect the line (infinitely many times). It intersects $y=\frac 12$ a few times but does not intersect $y=2$ at all.